# Run a standard command in bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am writing a bash script to automate several actions:

```
#!/bin/bash         

echo "Hello, World"
NAME="${1}"
PATH="${2}"
echo $NAME
echo $PATH
eval "ls"
```

I am going to call `ls, ffmpeg` and a lot of other commands.

However running my script gives me the following error:

```
/var/www/html# ./life.sh test midhand.mp4
+ ./life.sh test midhand.mp4
Hello, World
test
midhand.mp4
./life.sh: line 9: ls: command not found
```

How come? why not found? Maybe I should import a directory with scripts?

Comment: You need to be more clear. How are you running the script ? what is the intention of this script ?

Comment: To glue several videos

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The variable `PATH` is a special shell variable. It defines the list of directories in which executables/commands can be found.

In the line `PATH="${2}"`, you wipe out the default value of `PATH` and now the shell doesn't know where to find the `ls` command. For example, `ls` can be found in the directory `/bin`, but you modified `PATH` to have the value `midhand.mp4` (the second argument), in particular `PATH` does not contain `/bin` and thus your shell cannot find the `ls` command.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello, World"
the_name="${1}"
the_path="${2}"

echo "PATH is '$PATH'"
echo $the_name
echo $the_path
eval "ls"
```

**Note.** You can change the last line from `eval "ls"` to just `ls`.

You can run `man bash` to get further information.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this error message because you have changed the `PATH` environment variable to a command line argument (`${2}`) which dose not hold the actual binary.